# specific function of f-curve of animation key

Tags: python, animation, scripting

After inserting an animation key on an object
1) Is it possible to enter in a field (x, y, z) (x for example) of a f-curve (graph editor) an equation like these:

a) `y = 2 * (frame ^ 2) * cos (frame ^ 3)`
where `frame` is the name of the variable?

b) `y = 2 * (var1 ^ 2) * cos (3 ^ var2)`
where `var1` and `var2` are 2 different variables?

If not, is it possible to make it in python and if so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert the coefficients of a f-curve in Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/117611/how-to-insert-the-coefficients-of-a-f-curve-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible to combine FCurve modifiers to achieve more complex functions, usually it's simpler to add a **driver** which lets you enter a function.

[image: add driver]

To do that, right click on the field that you want to animate and select *Add Drivers* -> *Manually Create Later (Single)*.

[image: scripted expression]

In the Graph Editor in *Driver Mode* in the *Drivers* tab you can enter the formula. The variable `frame` can be used directly, but you can also add additional variables, e.g. based on other objects' coordinates.

Note that the exponentiation operator in Python is `**`. The caret `^` would be the bitwise XOR operator.